# Send via php post a text in html dom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, email

I Have two form in html5, which have a title (event). When the user subscribe to an event, I will send two email: one to my own mail and one to the user mail. In the mail for the user, I will write that he is successfully subscribed. And it works.
But I'd like to add also the name of the event (the content of the `h1` title) in the email. How can I do? Actually it leave an empty field in "event: " in the email's message.

Index.php:

```
<form  name="contact1" action="index.php" method="POST" id="contact1">    
    <h1 id="event">Event 1</h1>
    <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"   required /></div> 
    <div>Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div> 
</form>
<form name="contact2" action="index.php" method="POST" id="contact2">    
    <h1 id="event">Event 2</h1>
    <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"   required /></div> 
    <div>Email: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"  required /></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div> 
</form>


<div id="results"></div>
```

Before to close the `body` I insert the jquery code to send the values to contact.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form").submit(function() {
    // Getting the form ID
    var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
    var formDetails = $('#'+formID);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'contact.php',
        event:$("#event").text(),
        data: formDetails.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {  
            // Inserting html into the result div
            $('#results').html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
        // Displaying if there are any errors
            $('#result').html(error);           
    }
});
    return false;
});
});
```

This is the contact.php code:

```
<?php
    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

if(isset($_POST['email'])){
    $responso = "Success: request sent.";

    $email_to = "admin@admin.com"; // Send to admin
    $email_subject = "New user"; // Object Email to admin

    $first_name = $_POST['name']; // name of user  
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];   // email of user
    $event = $_POST['event']; // name of the event


    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email Address: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Evento: ".clean_string($event)."\n";



    // First mail to admin

    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

    // Second mail to new user      

    $email_subject2 = "Confirmation"; // Object Email to new user
    $email_message2 .= "Successful subscribed to ".clean_string($event)."\n";
    $email_message2 .= "dear ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $headers2 = 'From: '.$email_to."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_to."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_from, $email_subject2, $email_message2, $headers2); 

}else{
    $responso = "Error: Insert your email";
    } 
die( $responso );  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `$.ajax` doesn't have an `event` property in it's options.
You probably wanted to send that data with the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {

        var event_data  = encodeURIComponent( $("#event").text() );

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'contact.php',
            data: $(this).serialize() + "&event=" + event_data,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error) {
                $('#result').html(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: while I wait to pass the minimum minutes to put the best answer (you have been too fast :)) ) I take this opportunity to ask you another thing. Why don't I get the email if I do the registration with a hotmail address?

Comment: I'm not really sure, the email should be sent as long as the server is sending emails as it should, but it could be hotmail sees them as spam or something ?

Comment: Then I don't know, if the email arrives on other hosts, just not Hotmail, the problem is probably with Hotmail, not PHP